# To return the no of rows affected in oracle for complex queries

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have so many complex join queries, for which I want to return the number of rows affected.
Say for select 100, insert 50, etc..

I dont want to change the query for this operation. I tried `SQL%ROWCOUNT`. But it doesnt work. Please help me in this.

Comment: please make sure you spelled that correctly in your code, the name is `SQL%ROWCOUNT`. Also "does not work" is a very bad problem description. What error message did you get? what is it giving back? how exactly are you using it?

Answer (score 1):

To use sql%rowcount, you'll need to use it **directly** after the select/insert/update/delete.  For example:

```
declare
  v_date date;
  v_cnt pls_integer := 0;
  v_cnt2 pls_integer := 0;
begin

  select sysdate into v_date from dual;

  v_cnt := sql%rowcount;
  dbms_output.put_line('rowcount: ' || v_cnt);

  commit;

  v_cnt2 := sql%rowcount;
  dbms_output.put_line('rowcount2: ' || v_cnt2);

end;
```

Output:

```
rowcount: 1
rowcount2: 0
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to examine the inner workings of your query (cardinality of joined tables etc.) - is that right? If yes, you need to look at the execution plan Oracle generates for your query. Try a command like this:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM ...; // <-- insert your query here
SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display);
```

(See [SQL*Plus FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aPlus_FAQ#How_does_one_trace_.28and_explain.29_SQL_statements_from_SQL.2APlus.3F) for other options and more information.)